# Operation timed out - High Sierra

Tags: ruby, puma, macos-high-sierra, webpacker

Guys, so, yesterday I was upgrade to High Sierra.

After that - I can't start my project cause this error:

```
2017-09-27 16:52:48 +0300: Rack app error handling request { GET /unauthenticated }
#<Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out - user specified timeout>
```

with next logs:

```
/Users/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/socket.rb:61:in `connect_internal'
/Users/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/socket.rb:137:in `connect'
/Users/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/socket.rb:627:in `block in tcp'
/Users/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/socket.rb:227:in `each'
/Users/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/socket.rb:227:in `foreach'
/Users/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/socket.rb:617:in `tcp'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/webpacker-3.0.1/lib/webpacker/dev_server.rb:9:in `running?'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/webpacker-3.0.1/lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:7:in `rewrite_response'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rack-proxy-0.6.2/lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/server.rb:605:in `handle_request'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/server.rb:437:in `process_client'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/server.rb:301:in `block in run'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Is there someone ho already fixed it for himself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, to solve this issue is just needed to add the Github repository in your Gemfile and run `bundle update`:

```
gem 'webpacker', github: 'rails/webpacker'
```

Comment: Did you found out what could be the problem with the older webpacker version?

Comment: @hebergentilin Hey! I only found issue on github where contributors says that they specially publish new version of webpacker for high sierra